# Is the Prop Shop website down?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The link to the Prop Shop website listed on the Gazebo homepage: https://thepropshop.org/ seems to be dead. I have noticed this a couple of days ago. Websites like [Uptrends](https://www.uptrends.com) also report that the site is unreachable. Is this just a temporary interruption?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15532/is-the-prop-shop-website-down?/) by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, there is active work happening on The Propshop, but the website is not functional yet.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on 2017-03-13**:
Ok, thanks for the info! Are you wit the development team? Maybe it would be a good idea to put up a temporary page with this info, in stead of the page just timing out.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2017-03-13**:
Thanks, the propshop links have been removed from the gazebo web site. We'll work on a landing page soon.

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on 2017-03-13**:
Sounds good, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[https://thepropshop.org](https://thepropshop.org/) should be working again.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1